# Mon emploi n'est pas plus stable que mon couple

Tags: sens, négation

*Un chez-moi à mon coût* d'Éric Brassard :

> À l'enracinement du propriétaire s'oppose la liberté du locataire. Le
> locataire est par essence plus mobile et certains ne veulent pas
> s'engager à rester au même endroit longtemps. (...)
>
> ***Mon emploi n'est pas plus stable que mon couple**. Dans ces
> circonstances m'engager dans l'achat d'une maison n'est pas
> raisonnable.*

Je ne comprends pas le sens de la phrase *Mon emploi n'est pas plus stable que mon couple*. Sa signification devrait être *Mon emploi est plus instable que mon couple*. Mais que veut dire l'auteur par là ? Il y a toutes sortes de couples, stables et instables...

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it is not about the French language or its grammar.

Comment: @jlliagre Je ne pense pas que l'inversion soit obligatoire dans cette phrase _Mais que  l'auteur veut dire par là ?_ La phrase avec l'inversion est plus standard, mais sans l'inversion elle n'est pas incorrecte.

Comment: @Oreste Désolé de te contredire mais *Que l'auteur veut dire par là ?* est "impossible". Sans inversion, ce pourrait être : *Mais l'auteur veut dire quoi par là ?* ou *Mais c'est quoi, ce que l'auteur veut dire ?*

Comment: @jlliagre Mais pourquoi ? Par exemple, les phrases _Est-ce que tu aimes les lapins ?_ et _Tu aimes les lapins ?_ sont correctes, toutes les deux. La première est préférable à l'écrit, ma la 2ème reste correcte. Pourquoi alors _Mais que l'auteur veut dire  par là ?_ serait-elle impossible ? En raison de _que_ au début de la phrase ?

Comment: Probablement. Il faudrait écrire *Mais quoi l'auteur veut dire par là ?* pour que ce soit compris mais ça resterait extrêmement non standard.

Comment: La phrase _Que l'auteur veut dire par là ?_ est au moins compréhensible, bien qu'érronée, non ?

Comment: Elle demanderait un effort de compréhension à l'oral car ce n'est pas une faute qu'un francophone natif est susceptible faire spontanément. A l'écrit, on comprend et on se dit qu'il y a eu oubli de "qu'est-ce". C'est comme si on disait *Que tu veux ?* à la place de *Qu'est-ce que tu veux ? / Tu veux quoi ? / Que veux-tu ?*. La question *Que tu veux ?* est quand même assez incompréhensible.

Comment: @Oreste J'ai trouvé [cette page](http://www.madore.org/~david/weblog/d.2018-03-15.2496.html) à propos des pronoms en français. Elle devrait t'intéresser.

Comment: @jlliagre Oui, l'article est intéressant, et drôle en plus, merci ! Mais je suis sûre que le russe n'est pas plus logique que le français. Par contre, les anciennes langues comme l'arabe, l'hébreu et le chinois ont une grammaire plus simple. Je pense qu'il n'y a pas de futur ni passé en chinois. (L'un de mes enfants avait des amis chinois lorsqu'il était plus jeune, donc je connais quelques bases). L'hébreu et l'arabe sont vraiment des langues faciles. (l'arabe parlé, à l'écrit c'est une autre histoire)

Comment: Mais en ce qui concerne les déclinaisons, je pense que ce n'est pas du tout évident pour les étrangers. Il y en a 6 en russe.

Answer (score 1):

La phrase signifie :

1. mon couple n'est pas stable
2. mon emploi ne vaut pas mieux

C'est différent de *Mon emploi est plus instable que mon couple* qui ne porte pas de jugement aussi négatif sur la stabilité du couple en question et qui exclut que les deux soient aussi instables l'un que l'autre.